# Firebase integrating into IOS project - No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I created a simple multiple view IOS app in Swift 4 using Xcode 9.2. This app is nearly finished and works perfectly in the simulator and on a real IOS device. Before releasing the app, I would like to add some advertisement, analytics and crash recording functionality using Firebase. Therefor, I navigated to the official website and followed the required steps with CocoaPods, as suggested by this website.

What I did:

- Project works on device and simulator
- Closed Xcode
- I installed CocoaPods
- Edited the Pod file
- Run the Pod file (pod install)
- Opened the xcworkspace project with Xcode
- Added the GoogleService-Info.plist file to the project
- Tried to build the project ---> Shell Script Invocation Error

Showing Recent Errors Only

> /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-epcmbsjxqtkgaqfbhfycbmfcmvxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Last:
>   No such file or directory

No other warning flag are shown, just this error.

Any of you encountered this problem before? If yes, what did you do to solve this?

I tried:

- Opening closing Xcode
- Cleaning the project
- Restarting my mac
- Removing DerivedData from the folder pointed in 'workspace settings'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have added too much text in your question try to make as short as possible help to readers to get the rid of it

Comment: I reduced the amount of text in my question, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Which Shell Script does the error come from?

Comment: From run custom shell script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'

Comment: Do you have a library named "Last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: there were spaces in my app project folder and app projects name, Xcode and Cocoapods are not accepting these. I created a new project a project name without spaces, no problems at all! Thanks all for your help!